# C++ Como remover um elemento fora das extremidades de uma list

Tags: c++, lista

Utilizo a biblioteca list e estou com dificuldades para remover um elemento utilizando remove(), ou erase(). Com push_back() e push_front() funciona, mas preciso remover elementos que não estão nas extremidades..

Eu desejo passar o id do nó que desejo remover.

Já li a documentação do erase() e remove(), mas ainda não entendi.. Criei um exemplo básico para que vocês possam entender e conseguir me ajudar.

No.h:

```
#ifndef NO_H_INCLUDED
#define NO_H_INCLUDED

#include <list>

using namespace std;

class No
{
    int id;

    public:
    No(int id); // construtor
    int getId();
};

#endif // NO_H_INCLUDED
```

No.cpp:

```
#include "No.h"
#include <list>

No::No(int id){
    this->id=id;
}

int No::getId(){
    return this->id;
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "No.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<No> *listaNos;
    list<No>::iterator it;

    //adicionando valores a lista;
    listaNos = new list<No>;
    No noAux(10);
    listaNos->push_back(noAux);
    No noAux2(20);
    listaNos->push_back(noAux2);
    No noAux3(30);
    listaNos->push_back(noAux3);
    No noAux4(40);
    listaNos->push_back(noAux4);
    No noAux5(50);
    listaNos->push_back(noAux5);

    //exibindo a lista;
    for(it=listaNos->begin();it != listaNos->end();it++){
        cout << it->getId() << " ";
    }

    //remover o elemento 20; Como fazer?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dudu, bom que vc abriu outra pergunta sobre essa dúvida específica. Mas olha só, procure melhorar um pouquinho ela. Primeiramente você não deixa claro qual é a sua dificuldade (pelo que eu havia entendido vc quer remover um nó da lista *a partir de seu número de identificação*, certo? Se sim, coloque isso no texto da pergunta.). Outra coisa, procure fazer o exemplo ser um [mcve]. Para isso, coloque também o código mínimo da classe `No`. Por fim: por que é mesmo que vc faz tanta questão de usar o `vector` como um ponteiro? Vc entendeu que não precisa, né?

Comment: Sua ajuda esta sendo crucial, dessa forma estou tomando as decisões que você sugere. Editei a pergunta adicionando minha classe nó e especificando o que quero. Agora estou usando list e não mais vector. Quanto ao ponteiro, o trabalho é referente a uma implementação em grafos que tende a crescer muito, por algum motivo o professor sugeriu que usassemos ponteiro, acredito que seja devido a alguma funcionalidade futura... Conto com sua ajuda em mais essa questão @LuizVieira

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eis então uma solução:

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class No {
    private:
        int id;
    public:
        No(int id)
        {
            this->id = id;
        };

        int getId()
        {
            return id;
        };

        // Sobrecarrega o operador de comparação (para igualdade).
        inline bool operator==(const No &outro) const
        {
            return outro.id == this->id;
        }
};

int main()
{
    list<No> listaNos;
    list<No>::iterator it;

    //adicionando valores a lista;
    No noAux(10);
    listaNos.push_back(noAux);
    No noAux2(20);
    listaNos.push_back(noAux2);
    No noAux3(30);
    listaNos.push_back(noAux3);
    No noAux4(40);
    listaNos.push_back(noAux4);
    No noAux5(50);
    listaNos.push_back(noAux5);

    //exibindo a lista ANTES de remover
    cout << "ANTES DE REMOVER, A LISTA TEM:" << endl;
    for (it = listaNos.begin(); it != listaNos.end(); it++) {
        cout << it->getId() << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    //remover o no com Id 20
    listaNos.erase(std::remove(listaNos.begin(), listaNos.end(), No(20)));
    //ou:
    //listaNos.erase(std::remove(listaNos.begin(), listaNos.end(), noAux2));

    //exibindo a lista APÓS remover
    cout << "DEPOIS DE REMOVER, A LISTA TEM:" << endl;
    for (it = listaNos.begin(); it != listaNos.end(); it++) {
        cout << it->getId() << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Resultado desse código:

```
ANTES DE REMOVER, A LISTA TEM:
10 20 30 40 50
DEPOIS DE REMOVER, A LISTA TEM:
10 30 40 50
```

A ideia é sobrescrever (reimplementar) o operador de comparação para a igualdade na classe `No`. Assim, os métodos de remoção podem comparar e encontrar o Nó que vc quer remover com base no Id (note que o controle de como se compara tá dentro desse código - vc pode fazer como quiser/desejar).

Para a remoção, você não pode usar apenas o `listaNos.erase`, porque ele espera como parâmetro o iterador do item a ser removido. Assim, por isso você precisa encadear a chamada de `std::remove` no `listaNos.erase`.

Funcionaria também só com a chamada de `erase` usando aritimética de iteradores se vc soubesse qual é o índice do nó (e não seu Id), e *se você usasse `vector` no lugar de `list`* (porque o iterador do vetor é de acesso randômico, o da lista não). Por exemplo, se `listaNos` fosse um `vector`, você poderia fazer assim:

```
listaNos.erase(listaNos.begin() + 1); // O primeiro nó é índice 0, logo o segundo é índice 1
```

> Observações:
>
> 1. Se você precisar fazer outras coisas como ordenar usando algoritmos da STL (como o [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), por exemplo), você vai precisar
>      sobrescrever outros operadores de comparação. Nesse caso [a
>      documentação](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison) (e os exemplos dela) são úteis.
> 2. Note que eu intencionalmente não usei a lista como um ponteiro nesse código, porque não é realmente necessário *nesse exemplo*. [Você
>      comentou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/126514/c-como-remover-um-elemento-fora-das-extremidades-de-uma-list/126528#comment263743_126514) que seu professor disse que vai ter muitos nós, e que por
>      isso você entende que precisará ser ponteiro. Eu não concordo totalmente. Na prática,
>      tanto faz como vc vai usar. Mas para o seu aprendizado como
>      programador profissional, eu diria pra vc conversar com o seu
>      professor e procurar entender a motivação para isso. Vc vai aprender
>      muito a respeito. :)